# Serializing XML response from WebService to Object (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I am calling a REST webservice.

The response looks something like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<data>
  <status>1</status>
  <message>OK</message>
  <results>
    <result>
      <account>12345</account>
      <to>012345678</to>
      <from>054321</from>
      <message>Testing</message>
      <flash></flash>
      <replace></replace>
      <report></report>
      <concat></concat>
      <id>f8d3eea1cbf6771a4bb02af3fb15253e</id>
    </result>
  </results>
</data>
```

I have a class called "SMSSendingResponse" which looks like this:

```
public class SMSSendingResponse
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ResponseID { get; set; }
    public SMSMessage SMSMessage { get; set; }
}
```

SMSMessage looks like this:

```
public class SMSMessage
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I'm ignoring some of the returned elemenst (flash, replace etc..)

What's the best way of me serializing the returned XML into this object?

I tried using XmlSerializer, but this threw an error... I guess because I'm not serializing first using XmlSerializer.

If it were Json, I'd use the NewtonSoft.Json library...
Whilst i suppose i *could* convert xml to json, then serialize that way, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XmlSerializer` just fine as long as you add the appropriate attributes to the fields of your classes.  [Check these out for an example of some](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(VS.80).aspx).  You will undoubtedly run into errors the first few times you work with it, but stick with it because once you figure it out, it is a great tool.

EDIT:

[Here is a better place to find all of the available attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e123c76w(v=VS.100).aspx).  Look through the list for anything that begins with Xml and ends with Attribute.  You will want to know them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xsd.exe to extract schema from the xml file and generate corresponding c# class. You can use the generated class for serializing and deserializing the xml. If you show the code we will be able to identify mistake more easily.